# I don't have an xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, mouse, configuration, button

I'm trying to set up my extra mouse buttons but there is no xorg.conf in the `etc/X11/` directory. Is there something I have to do to create it? I haven't used Ubuntu for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no longer necessary...has not been needed for a while.  Xorg uses some built in intelligence so that it is not needed...
Now the extra keys in mice are recognised by the kernel but nor mapped to anything.  This may be sorted by using  xbindkeys... e.g. http://nxfifteen.me.uk/en/20130320/getting-logitech-custom-mouse-buttons-working-within-linux